# What is the canonicity of the Warcraft "cinematic universe"?

Tags: canon, warcraft, warcraft-2016

So I just watched Warcraft the movie. I suspect it differs from existing game lore of the same time period.

Just to be clear, I am quite familiar with Azerothian lore, having played WC III & WoW until 1-2 years ago. The lore is my favourite aspect of this universe, so I tend to read every bit of game text I encounter. However, I admit the time period portrayed in the movie is the weakest area of my knowledge, since I've never played WC I & II personally.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure the movie conflicts with official game lore at certain points, especially

> with regards to the fates of the Frostwolf Clan & of Thrall/Go'el's parents.

Are there any **official** statements addressing the relationship between Warcraft the movie and Warcraft the game series with regards to canonicity of content & its details?

Comment: I think this is the same with every movie adaptation from any other genre. Like the MCU is a different canon than many of the comic universes from Marvel. The basics are the same, but the details can differ quite a bit.

Comment: Perhaps. Nonetheless I'm looking for official confirmation on the direction the movies are taking.

Comment: @Thomas The MCU is perhaps a poor example, given that it's part of the same multiverse as the original comic universe.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, Blizzard has not made any attempt to clarify that either version of this story (the 2016 movie, or the original Warcraft I RTS game) should be held as canon over the other.

There have been relatively few times where they have directly commented on canon matters.  The majority that I can find relate to differences in characters as portrayed in various tie-in novels and directly in the games, and the general impression is that nothing should be taken as writ in stone. There have been several times where Warcraft history has been rewritten to accommodate the stories they want to tell, simply because the new material is cooler, or just plain newer, or other various reasons.  The Draenei example is probably the most famous for stirring controversy, although for sheer amount of rewritten history I understand the newly released *Chronicle* can't be beat.  Bottom line, game canon is a Doctor Who type of "everything is canon-ish" and should align to whatever makes more sense, with newer material having some preference.

The movie is an attempt to retell one of the older Warcraft stories, and doesn't make an attempt to tie to the current game events other than basing off them, so there's no indication of history revision here, other than slightly different plot details.  This would be consistent with most video adaptations of SFF media; its a choice to do what works on film (for better or worse), rather than being mandated into lockstep by the original work.

So I would suggest that, between the lack of statement and the flexible canon the Warcraft universe uses, the movie exists in it's own canon, rather than needing to somehow fit into the already zig-zagged lore of the game.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to an *official* statement is [a tweet by Micky Neilson](https://twitter.com/mickyneilson/status/620265824536793088) (who was at the time publishing lead and senior writer of Blizzard):

> Zerde3: @MickyNeilson Will the Warcraft movie become "canon" lore, or is it like a parallel universe like WoD? except no interaction between the two
>
> MickyNeilson: @Zerde3 Separate.

Based on this, I feel it's fairly safe to say that the movie officially exists in its own canon, as Radhil suggested.